# Filter with NSPredicate on custom object in Swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I want to filter on my custom object. My custom object look

```
class Requestlist: NSObject, NSCoding {
let artist: String
let title: String
let id: String
let type: String

init(artist: String, title: String, id: String, type: String) {
    self.artist = artist
    self.title = title
    self.id = id
    self.type = type
   }
}
```

But the program keeps crashing with this code:

```
    let textInput = txbSearch.text
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY artist contains[c] %@ OR title contains[c] %@",textInput!)
    let filteredArray = (Constants.liveRequestlist as NSArray).filtered(using: pred)
    print(filteredArray)
```

The code runs on KeyboardChange and must be updated when the keyboard input change like a live search. I also want to search on a part of an artist or title. (Like the SQL Like operator)

Comment: Already tried. But that doensn't work for Swift 3. https://imgur.com/a/lC9NP

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- `Any` is only for key paths or to-many relationships.
- The second parameter (representing the second `%@`) is missing.

  ```
  let pred = NSPredicate(format: "artist contains[c] %@ OR title contains[c] %@",textInput!, textInput!)
  ```

---

It's highly recommended to use the native Swift `filter` API:

```
let filteredArray = Constants.liveRequestlist.filter{ $0.artist.range(of: textInput!, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil 
                                               || $0.title.range(of: textInput!, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```